# Losing variable value in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables

I have a set of functions inside a function, the variable temp is being available in f1,f2,f3 but not f4. It says uncaught referenceerror: temp is not defined. When I use $scope.temp it works fine. Can someone help me why temp is not available in f4(). Thanks.

```
function(){
var temp = something;
f1(){}
f2(){}
f3(){
// added event listners
  f4();
}
f4(){
// temp is not available 
}

}
```

Comment: Look up closure. Many a topics. (Its actually the most voted javascript question on SO)

Comment: Is that correct syntax? Can you define functions like that -- `f1(){}`? do you mean `function f1(){}`? Or even `const f1 = function(){}`?

Comment: I tried, and temp is available in f4;)

Comment: Can you provide a running example that produces this error? (e.g. http://codepen.io).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you used var temp = something; **not this.temp**, the context will change by calling nested function.

Answer (score 0):

Your example never actually called f4, so I had to makes some assumptions, but it appears to be working just fine. If my assumptions about how your code is to be used are wrong, perhaps you could provide some more detail?

```js
function foo(){
  var temp = 'something';
  function f1(){}
  function f2(){}
  function f3(){
    // added event listners
    f4();
  }
  function f4(){
    // temp is not available 
    console.log(temp);
  }
  f3();
}

foo();
```